# how to change the default open-with program to a program on the second disk

Tags: windows-7, ssd, permissions, group-policy, default-settings

I have a 250GB HDD for my system and a 60GB SSD using a SATA port.

I installed most of my applications on the SSD.

There's a strange thing though. I can not change the default open-with program to a program which is on the SSD.

I think it may be caused by permission so I gave my user a 'full control' permission on the security tab in disk properties.

But changing permissions is not work.

After I choose an application (I've tried Notepad++, Sublime, 7Zip, etc.), nothing is added in the below window:

[image]

Also, if I install 7Zip on my machine, the right click menu items can not be added.

Comment: Did you browsed for that folder and added the software? Does it shows after adding it to the default programs list?

Comment: For 7zip context menu you **need** to run it (one time) as administrator (rightclick app and choose `run as admin.`) and enable it via the options. I have installed it on many computers and always needed to do this to add the context menu to the Explorer for 7zip. (Somehow it is not done during installation)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to edit registry.

**WARNING: When editing registry always be extra careful and backup your registry before making any changes**

Launch [regedit](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tools_regeditors.mspx?mfr=true) and navigate to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\{Application Name}\shell\open\command
```

Replace the {Application Name} with whatever application you are looking at : Notepad++ or Sublime Text.

[image]

In `command` key, select "`Default value`" and double check the path to the executable and make sure it is correct. Make any edits necessary, then close regedit. Note that value also includes the argument. Here is example of what I have for my Notepad++ installed on none system drive:

[image]

Your "Open With dialog should work now"